# .Net library/component for OS Fingerprinting?

Tags: .net, fingerprinting

Can anyone recommend a (preferably gratis) .Net library/component to perform OS Fingerprinting?

I'm writing a program that will verify if a list of hosts are up, and at the same time perform OS Fingerprinting to determine the OS of the hosts.

The background: My predecessor left me a legacy of Active Directory + DNS that has not been housekept for $DEITY-knows-when. I want to identify which of the entries are still up, which are no longer reachable, while also trying to detect Windows OSes that for unknown reasons are not joined to the domain but exist in the DNS.

Comment: Are you wanting to fingerprint the OS installation, or just the hardware you're installed on?

Comment: Ah sorry, I might not be clear enough; I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

If the machines are on the domain and you have sufficient privileges, you can use WMI (Windows Management Interface) to query information about remote machines. It's fairly easy to work with from .Net

You might need to use group policy to push out a firewall rule to allow incoming WMI traffic, but aside from that detail it's pretty straightforward.

- [MSDN - Connecting to WMI on a Remote Computer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa389290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#configuring_a_computer_for_a_remote_connection)
- [MSDN - Using WMI with C#](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-WMI-with-C-4e5a9ee1)

Comment: Interesting... but it the host is not AD-joined but exist in the DNS, won't trying to do a WMI query results in long delay as the "querier" waits for timeout?

Comment: If the machine you're connecting to isn't AD joined then you'd have to connect using the local administrator account instead. Try one, then the other - and grab a few cups of coffee while it does its thing.